# DOCTYPE in the head of the page causes session_problem

Tags: php, html, session

i had this error in my site:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - 
headers already sent (output started at /home/rentedco/public_html/try6.php:2) in 
/home/rentedco/public_html/try6.php on line 2
```

i have created a simple php file containing only the beggining of the other pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start();
echo 'fsdf';
?>
```

and i discovered that if i remove the DOCTYPE i dont get this problem anymore, my problem is that i dont want to ruin something else by removing this header.
can i remove it? can i pt it after the session_start call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, putting the doctype out there pushes data onto the PHP output buffer, but the session_start() requires writing cookie data to the header. The doctype is part of the HTML page, and not the header, so it should be safe to put it in after the session_start().

Comment: thank you for your answer. do i have to write the DOCTYPE anyway? what does this tag do?

Comment: Doctype defines how the browser should parse the HTML. When you just have <!DOCTYPE html> you've defined the page as HTML5. Here's some more info: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles

Answer (score 0):

**session_start()** should always be written at the beginning or else it will not work same as **header()** function.

Answer (score 0):

Session start has to be called before any output gets sent to the browser change your code to

```
<?php session_start(); ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    echo "fsdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this idea. You can start and stop the php interpreter as many times as you like, but session_start() must happen before your start sending any html to the browser.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
....
....
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo 'fsdf';
?>
</body>
</html>
```