# DOCTYPE causing external stylesheet to not function when using PHP as handler

Tags: php, apache2, doctype

I'm having trouble with external style sheets working when passing requests through Apache2's SetHandler, a PHP script and when specifying a DOCTYPE in the document.  Without the DOCTYPE declared the page works fine with the external stylesheet.  This is on Apache 2.2.15, PHP 5.3.3 and also under Apache 2.4.6, PHP 5.5.3.

My Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /data/www/test
<Directory "/data/www/test/_auth">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
Action VerifyAuth /_auth/authenticate_test.php
<Directory "/data/www/test/testsite">
    SetHandler VerifyAuth
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My authenticate_test.php file:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

The index.html file I'm testing with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/testsite/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Test Site</h1>
</body></html>
```

The stylesheet I'm testing with (mainstyle.css):

```
h1 { background:black; color:blue; width:100px; display: block;}
```

When I check the logs I can see the stylesheet is being read with a 200 return code but the stylesheet formatting does not get applied.  Again, when removing the DOCTYPE the page loads as expected.  I can embed the style in the html file which also works but I need to be able to make use of the external style sheets.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have all requests passed through an authentication script written in PHP for any and all content being accessed under the testsite directory.  Because there will be content I do not want to necessarily customize by removing all DOCTYPE declarations from each page I would like to get this working whether or not a DOCTYPE is declared.

I have tried this with Chromium 28.0.1500.71 (ubuntu 13.04), Firefox 24.0 (ubuntu 13.04), and IE9 (Win 7).

Comment: There is no other code on the page? And what happens with a different doctype?

Comment: There is no other code on the page.  I've tried to break this problem down as simply as I could to help figure out what's going on.  The other doctypes don't change the behavior.  Any doctype results in the styles not rendering.  I've been looking at his more and using the Chrome dev tools I see this: "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html" for my style sheet.  I guess the HTML is passing through the handler as PHP with the include statement but the MIME type for the CSS isn't text/css when using the DOCTYPE.

Comment: what's weird is I get this same message when I remove the DOCTYPE yet the content is displayed properly.

Comment: I am unable to answer my own question at this time since I'm a newb to the site.  But here is my answer:
Unfortunately, I only just now found this on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429844/doctype-in-the-head-of-the-page-causes-session-problem).

Changing my auth PHP handler to this has fixed my issue:

    <?php
    $type =
    (get_object_vars(apache_lookup_uri($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
    header('Content-type: '.$type['content_type']);
    readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    ?>

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I only just now found this on stackoverflow ([DOCTYPE in the head of the page causes session_problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429844/doctype-in-the-head-of-the-page-causes-session-problem)).

Changing my auth PHP handler to this has fixed my issue:

```
<?php
$type =
(get_object_vars(apache_lookup_uri($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
header('Content-type: '.$type['content_type']);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```